# Should I remove my unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I have posted a few questions on here that have not been met with a response. Going over them, I still do not have an answer, but I would not be able to confirm an answer or mark it as "most helpful", due to no longer having that particular project.

[In one case](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/117756/rigidbody-constrains-like-to-invert-themselves), I still have no idea why a particular function was behaving like it was 'opposite day', to the point where I would not even be able to replicate the problem to confirm a solution. [In another case](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106598/soundeffect-play-and-soundeffectinstance-play-do-not-work), the issues were encountered in an environment that I would preferably never have to use, again, in this life or the next.

**Should** somebody come along with the same problem, I can see my questions being a hindrance. They would be 'originals' for a duplication close, but offer no help. In the case where future answers would make them helpful I still feel that a newer question, where the problem is still in the asker's interests and they are able to judge a question as most helpful, would be an improvement to the overall quality. I also know that deleting questions can sometimes lead to the user being punished in unforeseen ways.

Should I delete the questions, or leave them be? Is there a way to mark them as "abandoned" in a way that would be more helpful, in the given context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no particular reason to delete them, except your own peace of mind. There's no way to mark them "abandoned" or whatever but it shouldn't matter much.

If you want, delete them (the ones you can at least). But otherwise they don't cause any issues.